# Creating a View That Can Filter on Lookup Column

Tags: lookup-column, filter, view

I have a list with a column called Function that is of type Lookup. I try to create a view in the list and I attempt to Filter below:

[image]

I click OK at the bottom of the page and I get the below error:

[image]

It tells me that filtering on a column of type Lookup is not supported. Is there a work around to this or is there a different way that I can create a view that filters on my Function column?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another column of type Single Line of Text and create a workflow that automatically runs on Add and Update that copies the value of the lookup column to it, then filter on that column.

Comment: That sounds good but what about the other 160 items I have on the list prior to making the workflow and the single line of text? That means I would have to manually start for all in order to make sure I can capture everything and not just current items on the list?

Comment: @Aspire27 there are a variety of ways to deal with that. A brute force way is to edit the existing items in data sheet view and paste a dummy value in the new field all the way down In each row. That will force the workflow to run on each row and overwrite the dummy value with the lookup value. You can also find Powershell scripts on the web that iterate through a list and run a workflow on each item, or really you just need to run Update() on each row.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you the contains operator is not valid in this configuration, you can filter using lookup columns, but you are restricted to equals or not equals.

So you'd need to create a view with a filter of your columns equals AGNXYZ or your column equals AGNABC, etc

Comment: Hi Eric. The only issue with that is with Equal To it has to be the exact text. So if in my column Function if I have entries that are Travel, Travels and Travelers then this won't work. If I set the filter to equal to TRAV, it doesn't pick up any if the aforementioned examples.

Comment: I know, you have to be explicit, because of the limitation that you cannot use the contains operator in a lookup column filter. Which is why I said it isn't valid, and you have to use equal to.

Comment: I understand. I have 20 items that I want to display in my view but filtering only allows me to do 10 filters max it seems like. Is there a workaround you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to modify the list view using SharePoint Designer. Using SPD one can write CAML query to fetch records for list view. 
[Refer this link](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2014/05/sharepoint-designer-2013-how-to-modify-list-view-filters-parameters/)